# Not getting limits of integration right (triple integrals)?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Calculate the volume bounded by $y+z=1$, $z=x^2-1$, $z=1-x^2$ and $y=0$

So our volume $V=\int \int \int _D1 dA$, all that's left is figuring out limits of integration. One method I saw was looking at the traces on the $xy, yz, xz$-planes.

The trace on the $xy-$plane indicates that $x$ goes from -1 to 1, and that $y$ goes from 0 to 1.

The trace on the $yz$ plane indicates that $z$ goes from $1$ to the line $z=1-y$, and now it indicates that $y$ goes from 0 to 2. Why is this? Am I doing anything wrong?

And the $xz$ trace indicates $z$ goes from $x^-1$ to $1-x^2$, but what limits should I actually choose?

Thanks for any explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take the $z-x$ plane to be "in the plane of the paper" ($+z$ points right and $+x$ points to the top of the page), and $+y$ points out of the paper.

The equations $z = 1 - x^2$ and $z = x^2 - 1$ are parabolas opening to the left and right, respectively.  Since $y$ can be anything, the surfaces are parabolic sheets.

The equation $y=0$ is the plane of the paper ($z$ and $x$ can each be anything).

The volume from these three equations is an oddly-shaped, half-infinite cylinder with its axis being the $+y$ axis.

The equation $y+z = 1$ is a sheet that slopes down into the page, toward the right, with slope of $1$.  The trace of this sheet in the $z-x$ plane is the line $z=1$.  This plane cuts the half-infinite cylinder, and defines your volume.

In the $x$ direction, the limits are from $-1$ to $1$.  That's where your parabolas intersect on the $x$ axis.

The limits in the $z$ direction will be from $x^2-1$ to $1-x^2$, in between the two parabolas.

Finally, the limits in the $y$ direction, with respect to $z$, will be $0$ to $1-z$.

Putting it all together:

$$V =   \int_{-1}^{1} dx \int_{x^2-1}^{1-x^2} dz \int_{0}^{1-z} dy.$$